# Phonegap WP7 app not perform any functionality

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, cordova

I am working on `Cordova` hybrid mobile app currently am doing in android app it runs fine now when i make same app for window phone it is not perform any functionality.

for make WP8 I follow this [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/guide_getting-started_windows-phone-8_index.md.html#Windows%20Phone%208%20Platform%20Guide) after that i copy my all file of `www` folder to new generated `www` in `Visual Studio` project.

But when i ran app it just shows its first page only and not performing any functionality.

So what steps did i miss ?
On the `click` of `button` I `call` following function

```
$('#contactBackupBtn').on('click',function(){
    $('#p2').append("Going to be backup");
    sm_sync.backupAllTheContacts(function(){
        $('#p4').append("After Contact Backup Function Finished ");
    });
});
```

From above `function` it `calls` the following one

```
backupAllTheContacts:function(callback) {
    $('#p3').append("IN backupAllTheContacts");
    navigator.contacts.find(["*"], function(contacts) {
        $('#p3').append("IN Contact Success");
        callback();
    }, sm_sync.onError, {"multiple": true});  
}

onError:function(error) {
    $('#p1').empty();
    $('#p1').append(error.code);
    $('#p1').append(error.message);
}
```

When i execute it, it shows this message `IN backupAllTheContacts` and ths `Going to be backup` but not showing any success or error messages. what should i do to make it run.

(This is a small part of my app it is runnng perfact in Android Emulator but not n windows
I need help i am stuck here)

Comment: are you localstorage in your project

Comment: yes am using that but not in start of app but yeah somewhere in mid it will be use

Comment: Did you resolve this issue ? if you found any answer helpful then mark it. If you resolve it yourself then please post it here as answer so that it may be helpful to someone else.

Comment: Not resolve yet.  I dont know what happened there? no alert,console.log showing nothing happened.  Is there anyways to see logs (like logcat in eclipse )

Answer (score 0):

use console.log is not support in windows phone so use this and use localStorage like this. try to run on deviceready

```
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {

      /* This is for Console.log support in WP */

        if (typeof window.console == "undefined") {
            window.console = {
                log: function (str) {
                    window.external.Notify(str);
                }
            };
        }


        var key0;

      /* manage localstorage this way */

        if (typeof (window.localStorage) !== "undefined") {
            localStorage.setItem('lastname', "Smith");

            localStorage.firstname = "One";

            if (localStorage.getItem('objectKey1') != null || localStorage.getItem('objectKey1') != undefined) {
                key0 = window.localStorage.getItem('objectKey1');
            }


        }


    },false);
```

Comment: use that separately? or in my app? and what is this for?

Comment: in your app first all code past on device ready and than use localstorage like this

Answer (score 0):

When i build my WP8 app i ran into somewhat an issue same as this. it's because of the jQuery i used. Then i updated my jQuery to the latest and its all started working fine.

Please check the jQuery documentation and the version you are using. Or you just put up your code in here so that we can have a closer look.

> "But when i ran app it just shows its first page only and not performing any functionality.
>
> So what steps did i miss ?"
>
> Without the code how can we say what steps did you missed ???

Comment: its bit a long time but I updated my question and please i need help in that